# How to execute multiple statements in Presto?

Tags: presto

I need to run multiple lines of code in Presto together. Here is example.

```
drop table if exists table_a
drop table if exists table_b
```

The above gives me error:

```
SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#20190820_190638_03672_kzuv6): line 2:1: mismatched input 'drop'. Expecting: '.', <EOF>
```

I already tried adding ";", but no luck.

Is it possible to stack multiple statements or I need to execute line by line? My actual example involves many other commands such as `create table` and etc.

Comment: Which client tool are you using? It depends on the tool.

Comment: You can use `presto-cli --file script.sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use presto command line option to submit the sql file which may consist many sql commands.

```
/presto/executable/path/presto client --file $filename
```

Example:

```
/usr/lib/presto/bin/presto client --file /my/presto/sql/file.sql
```